# A little riddle for you

Tags: riddle

*Not mathematical yet I represent a half of sorts,*

*With furrowed brows and a holey sign I am formed,*

*My colouring a little 'boorish' you could say,*

*My opposite North-eastern?!*

What am I?

> It is a symbol.

> Think about what Boor sounds like? And what colour is often associated with that?

Comment: Would [[tag:word]] apply? It is to be used when the answer is a word.

Comment: No, it is not a word.

Comment: Do you mean "holey" or "holy"? Just checking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> ♀

Not mathematical yet I represent a half of sorts,

> The ♀ symbol represents the female sex, members of which make up roughly half of the global human population.

With furrowed brows and a holey sign I am formed,

> **From the OP:** "furrowed brows" indicates "cross" and "holey" refers to the circle above it.

My colouring a little 'boorish' you could say,

> **From the OP:** 'boorish' is meant to indicate 'like a boar or pig' and refers to the colour pink. There is a common modern connection between the colour pink and femininity and this often leads to the symbol being depicted in pink.
>  **Original Answer:** ♀ is also the symbol for the planet Venus which looks coarsely coloured as you can see.
>  [image]
>  Also "boor" sounds like "beer" and the colour of Venus does somewhat resemble a beer settling.

My opposite North-eastern?!

> The symbol for male is ♂ which, as you can see, is a circle with an arrow pointing to the North-East.

Comment: Boor=Boar=Pig which is pink in colour.

Comment: Also furrowed brows=cross and holey = hole.

Comment: Please correct your answer.

Comment: @Smartest1here Thanks, will edit in your suggestions. I should say that, even though a pig is usually pink, a boar is a specific animal which is brown/black in colour. Also, the symbol in question is not really associated with pink but more often red or green.

Comment: @Smartest1here The furrowed brows bit is very clever though.

Comment: I am sure a search google images will defy that claim about the symbol's common colouring .

Comment: @Smartest1here I can see where you coming from but when I do a google image search, it mostly comes up as black.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be

> The angry face emoticon: **>:O**

Not mathematical yet I represent a half of sorts,

> You look like "greater than zero" which is essentially half of the real numbers

With furrowed brows and a holey sign I am formed,

> The **>** indicates the furrowed brow, and the **O** "holey sign" the open mouth

My colouring a little 'boorish' you could say,

> In emoji world (hinted by "coloring"), the equivalent is  which in some platforms has an angry red tint (very much not sure about this clue...)

My opposite North-eastern?!

> On a keyboard, north east from **>** is **:**, and north east from **O** is **)** - put them together, and you have :) which is the opposite of >:O

Comment: This is not the answer.

Comment: Hint: Think about what Boor sounds like? And what colour is often associated with that?

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

> 225

---

My colouring a little 'boorish' you could say,

> the color of rgb 225

With furrowed brows and a holey sign I am formed,

> the number's shape.

My opposite North-eastern?! (I got the hint from this)

> Northeast (NE), 45°'s opposite is 225°

I don't know about the first clue.

Comment: Hint: The answer is not aiming at any alphanumerical characters per se.

Comment: @Smartest1here What do you mean?

Comment: @Smartest1here So this is wrong?

Comment: Yes it is......

Answer (score 0):

I think its

> St

> st is 2 out of 5 letters of sorts.if we rotate st 90degree we see a eyebrow shape and a cross .st stands for sao tome which is a south western country also

Comment: Nope, please think again and improve your answer!

Comment: it is not a word

Answer (score 0):

Lines 1 and 4 make me think of

> ♀️ (half of the population is female, opposite is ♂️).

I have no idea, what the boorish colour would be (

> pink maybe?

) and I really don't see the furrowed brows though.

Comment: A good answer should explain every part of the riddle, because the intended answer will be able to.